# $_SESSION variables use in queries

Tags: session, string

I have spent nearly two days going in circles on this one.

I seem to have difficulty  using $_SESSION or $_POST as strings in any query or converting them to strings to use.

I am using a simple hash approach to login to a site.

Extract from script is

```
<?php
session_start();    
echo "******Running Authenticate<br>";
echo "data submitted<br>".$_POST['site_login']."<br>".$_POST['site_password']."<br><br>";
$SiteLogin =  $_POST['site_login']
$_SESSION['site_login'] = $_POST['site_login'];
$_SESSION['site_password'] = $_POST['site_password'];
$_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();
$_SESSION['Now_val']  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//include 'showallvars.php';
include 'dbconfig.php';
// Prepare our SQL 
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT site_index, site_password FROM web_sites WHERE site_login = ?')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['site_login']);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.


if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();   

    echo "account exists";   
    }
    else
    {
    header('Location: badindex.php');
    }

if (password_verify($_POST['site_password'], $password)) {
// Verification success! User has loggedin!
echo "password good";

}
else
{
header('Location: badindex.php');
}
}

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;


?>
```

that works fine

BUT there is another field ( 'site_name') in the  record which i want to carry forward.
This should be easy !!

and there is a dozen ways of doing it 
 for example  the "standard" example is something like

```
$name = $mysqli->query("SELECT site_name FROM web_sites WHERE site_login = 'fred'")->fetch_object()->site_name;
```

That works fine 
but no matter how i try - concatenating or or ... I cannot get $_SESSION['site_login'] or $_POST['site_login'] to replace 'fred'.
There seems to be white space added in.

Assistance or guidance ?

Comment: Please don't post multiple contradictory answers. Conjecture and faultfinding should be edited into your question and you should post a single answer detailing your solution. You can edit both your questions and answers to correct them as necessary. You should consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Isn't this a PHP question? Shouldn't it be on SO instead?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to as easy as doing the following:

So:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT site_index, site_password 
    FROM web_sites WHERE site_login = ?')) {
```

becomes:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT site_index, site_password, site_login 
    FROM web_sites WHERE site_login = ' . $SiteLogin)) {
```

Do note, it is bad practice to do directly parse $SiteLogin to a query, because now someone can SQL Inject this and hack your website. All they need to do is use your form and figure out that which field is responsible for $SiteLogin. You would need to escape your $SiteLogin. Assuming Mysqli, it would become:

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT site_index, site_password, site_login 
    FROM web_sites WHERE site_login = ' . $con->real_escape_string($SiteLogin))) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that BUT the instant I saw the curly brackets in your answer  - it all came flooding back to me.  I had forgotten that PHP has problems with the square brackets

```
 $sql = ("SELECT site_name FROM web_sites WHERE site_login = '". $_SESSION{'site_login'} ."' LIMIT 1");
```

I KNEW it was easy !

Your comments on injection are of course correct but this was an edited code  excerpt and $SiteLogin was just added in as a "temporary working variable if needed"

Comment: You should at least vote up my answer if it helped you.

Comment: apologies - I managed to blue screen myself in a fit of enthusiasm !